# French news sites about IT

Tags: informatique, ressources

I'm searching for a french news site about computer science, not the usual consumer electronic/computer sites.
My preferred subjects are:

- coding
- linux
- networking
- general IT news

heise.de is a good (but german) example for what I'm looking for.
(It's hard to find non consumer oriented sites, I've tried to google for sites in french)

Comment: Have a visit to linuxfr.org

Answer (score 3):

I like to read [Korben](http://korben.info)'s blog which is very popular amongst french-speaking developpers.

Another good website, although less technical but great for tech news is [Numerama](http://numerama.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Developpez.com](http://www.developpez.com/) is a community based web site focused on software development but also talks about the other topics you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Some websites from google search :

- [Journal du Net](http://www.journaldunet.com/web-tech/developpeur/)
- [ZDNET](http://www.zdnet.fr/actualites/)
- [le Monde informatique](http://www.lemondeinformatique.fr/)
- [Silicon](http://www.silicon.fr/)
- [HumanCoders](http://news.humancoders.com/)

Comment: He asked for : "not the usual consumer electronic/computer sites"

Comment: @Stéphane click on my links and tell me what are the usual consumer websites.

Comment: apart the last one they're all filled with advertising.

Comment: @Stéphane now, have you been on [heise.de], the website that OP likes? A lot of free websites have some ads, that not enought to make those websites consumer ones. Those I linked are IT oriented.

Comment: Well, I might have misunderstood "consumer sites". (But I haven't downvoted your answer though). Have a nice day!

Comment: @Stéphane I don't exactly know what OP wants but I read what he wrote. Just wanting to defend my pov, no worries. You too, sir.

Comment: With "usual consumer computer sites" I mean pages that explain how to use windows or how to install or start a program. I'm an IT professional and would like to read my IT news (new linux kernel developments, security news, general IT news, dev news) in french to consolidate my `french learning` and `read up on tech` tasks ;)

Comment: @wullxz You should have added those information in your question. ;) If none of the above websites please you, tell me and I'll delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few websites I like:

- http://www.hardware.fr
- http://linuxfr.org/
- https://www.journalduhacker.net/